# MS Access checkbox default value is not updating on form record navigation

Tags: ms-access

I have a single form on contacts table and few checkboxes on it.
[image]

Check box is updating another Contact-CustType table to define relation between contact and cuttype:
[image]

I am fetching the user entry status for custtype through DLookup function in default value:
[image]

It's all working fine but when I am using form navigation the check boxes are not updating.

I tried requery , refresh method to refresh checkbox control but its not seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Place your formula to Control Source property with "=" at the beginning, not to Default Value

**UPDATE**

If you need to handle events from checkbox, then leave Control Source empty and set checkbox value in `Current` form event. Something like this:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
Check15.Value=Nz(DLookup("[ContactID]","Contact_CustType","[ContactID]=" & [ID] & " AND [CustTypeID]=1") > 0,False)
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @Sergey , Thanks for your answer it helpd and started to work but now it stopped the check box to trigger VBA to update Contact-CustType table.

Private Sub Check15_Click()
If Check15.Value = 0 Then
    str_sql = "Delete * from Contact_CustType where ContactID = " & ID & " and CustTypeID =" & 1
Else
    If Check15.Value = -1 Then
        str_sql = "Insert into Contact_CustType(CustTypeID, ContactID) values(" & 1 & ", " & ID & ")"
    End If
End If
DoCmd.RunSQL str_sql
End Sub

Comment: Sorry, missed you requirement for updating another tables. Pushing values to controls works faster than pulling using formula in Control Source

Comment: Please post what did you place in OnCurrent form's event

Comment: There is nothing placed at OnCurrent , the above code is placed OnClick event of checkbox and the Dlookup on default value section of checkbox.

Comment: If you noticed, I updated my answer. You need to move your formula you used in Default Value property to OnCurrent form's event, it should assign value to checkbox